# Is it possible to train two separated networks based on the loss of one of them? (Tensorflow custom optimization)

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, loss

Due to memory limitation, I had to separate the two networks (CNN and BLSTM)  in the feedforward prop and do the back prop on both networks at the same time. However, it seems that only the BLSTM weights get updated and CNN weights stay the same!

My implementation is quite long to post it here, but I have modified this regression TF example from GitHub and I followed the same procedure with my CNN+BLSTM model

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy

tf.reset_default_graph()
rng = numpy.random

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 25
display_step = 1

# Training Data
train_X = numpy.asarray([3.3,4.4,5.5,6.71,6.93,4.168,9.779,6.182,7.59,2.167,
                         7.042,10.791,5.313,7.997,5.654,9.27,3.1])
train_Y = numpy.asarray([1.7,2.76,2.09,3.19,1.694,1.573,3.366,2.596,2.53,1.221,
                         2.827,3.465,1.65,2.904,2.42,2.94,1.3])
n_samples = train_X.shape[0]

# tf Graph Input
X1 = tf.placeholder("float")
X2 = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

# Set model weights
with tf.variable_scope('net1'):
    W1 = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight1")
    b1 = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias1")
    # Construct a linear model1
    pred1 = tf.add(tf.multiply(X1, W1), b1)

var1 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='net1')

with tf.variable_scope('net2'):
    # Set model weights
    W2 = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight2")
    b2 = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias2")
    # Construct a linear model2
    pred2 = tf.add(tf.multiply(X2, W2), b2)

# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred2-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)

# Gradient descent
var2 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='net2')
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost, var_list=var1+var2)

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (x, y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
            feat = sess.run(pred1, feed_dict={X1: x})
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X2: feat, Y: y})

        # Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X2: train_X, Y:train_Y})
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), \
                "W1=", sess.run(W1), "b1=", sess.run(b1), \
                "W2=", sess.run(W2), "b2=", sess.run(b2))
```

Output:

```
Epoch: 0001 cost= 1.897011757 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.148642 b2= -0.452278
Epoch: 0002 cost= 1.914609313 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.147074 b2= -0.451319
Epoch: 0003 cost= 1.913563490 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146999 b2= -0.450277
Epoch: 0004 cost= 1.912214637 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146948 b2= -0.449235
Epoch: 0005 cost= 1.910862923 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146898 b2= -0.448194
Epoch: 0006 cost= 1.909512877 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146847 b2= -0.447153
Epoch: 0007 cost= 1.908164740 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146797 b2= -0.446114
Epoch: 0008 cost= 1.906818390 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146747 b2= -0.445076
Epoch: 0009 cost= 1.905474305 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146696 b2= -0.444039
Epoch: 0010 cost= 1.904131770 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146646 b2= -0.443003
Epoch: 0011 cost= 1.902791142 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146596 b2= -0.441968
Epoch: 0012 cost= 1.901452661 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146546 b2= -0.440934
Epoch: 0013 cost= 1.900115728 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146496 b2= -0.439901
Epoch: 0014 cost= 1.898780823 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146446 b2= -0.438869
Epoch: 0015 cost= 1.897448182 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146396 b2= -0.437838
Epoch: 0016 cost= 1.896116853 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146346 b2= -0.436808
Epoch: 0017 cost= 1.894787788 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146296 b2= -0.43578
Epoch: 0018 cost= 1.893460274 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146246 b2= -0.434752
Epoch: 0019 cost= 1.892134905 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146196 b2= -0.433725
Epoch: 0020 cost= 1.890811205 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146147 b2= -0.4327
Epoch: 0021 cost= 1.889489293 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146097 b2= -0.431675
Epoch: 0022 cost= 1.888169646 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.146047 b2= -0.430651
Epoch: 0023 cost= 1.886851430 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.145998 b2= -0.429629
Epoch: 0024 cost= 1.885535717 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.145948 b2= -0.428607
Epoch: 0025 cost= 1.884221435 W1= 2.462 b1= 2.34888 W2= 0.145899 b2= -0.427587
```

The trick I'm trying to use is that I pass the two variable lists to the optimizer `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost, var_list=var1+var2)` but it seems that only `w2` and `b2` are getting updated and `w1` and `b1` stays the same. Any idea if this task is possible or if there is something wrong in my implementation?

UPDATE:

the only indirect connection between `net1` and `net2` is happing in the training loop

```
feat = sess.run(pred1, feed_dict={X1: x})
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X2: feat, Y: y})
```

where I get the feature from `net1` and use that as input for `net2`, that is where I need `pred1`. I cannot use this connection in the graph as for the original example CNN+BLSTM that I'm using the two networks use different batch sizes, so they have to be separated in the forward prop.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the first network (`pred1`) doesn't appear anywhere in the cost calculations. Thus the gradients for the variables involved in calculating it are 0, since changing them wouldn't change the cost at all. Your first network serves absolutely no purpose in this setup.

If you want `net1`'s variables to be updated, you need to use them somewhere. For example, you could use the mean of `pred1` and `pred2` as the network output instead.

Comment: the only indirect connection between `net1` and `net2` is happing in the training loop `feat = sess.run(pred1, feed_dict={X1: x})` `sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X2: feat, Y: y})` where I get the feature from `net1` and use that as input for `net2`, that is where I need `pred1`. I cannot use this connection in the graph as for the original example CNN+BLSTM that I'm using the two networks use different batch sizes, so they has to be separated in the forward prop.

Comment: Whoops, didn't see that. This doesn't work since in the second `run` call Tensorflow doesn't "know" that `feat` is the output of `net1`. I don't understand why you cant just use the same batch sizes in both cases.

Comment: The BLSTM seq length is very long, it won't fit in the memory if I used the same batch size for the CNN. I did this separation just as a workaround. If there is something else I could do and make it work properly that would also be sufficient!